# How to set up avatar for google group?

Tags: google-groups

We are using Google Groups for managing access to our Google resources like GDocs, GDrive, Youtube videos etc. It works great, but we would like to set up avatars for them. Currently it looks ugly:

[image: screenshot from GDocs]

[image: screenshot from GDrive]

So, how can I change default pics for my groups? I was trying to find this feature in GGroups UI or support pages - no result.

Answer (score 1):

As of Sept 2021 it's not possible for a Google Group to have an avatar. It only shows a generic photo.

Please go here to request the feature: https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Feature-Ideas/cmp-p/grouphub%3Aworkspace-ideas-group

Comment: This question never got an answer because it's off topic and should be closed. Do not answer off topic questions. [answer]